# Android fragments - The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create an app with a navigation drawer. It works well till I try to add another TextView above the list view in my navigation drawer fragment. Then it gives this exception when I try to setContentView in my HomeActivity:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Here's all the relevant code:

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml: **(The fb_name textview is what I need to add.)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fb_name"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="First Last"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#ffcdcdcd"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is where I inflate the fragment -

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) group.findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });

    ArrayList<DrawerItem> drawerItems = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    DrawerItem drawerItem1 = new DrawerItem("Home", R.drawable.home);
    DrawerItem drawerItem2 = new DrawerItem("Start a Contest", R.drawable.hand_point);
    DrawerItem drawerItem3 = new DrawerItem("All Contests", R.drawable.briefcase);
    DrawerItem drawerItem4 = new DrawerItem("My Contests", R.drawable.binoculars);
    DrawerItem drawerItem5 = new DrawerItem("Login", R.drawable.home);

    drawerItems.add(drawerItem1);
    drawerItems.add(drawerItem2);
    drawerItems.add(drawerItem3);
    drawerItems.add(drawerItem4);
    drawerItems.add(drawerItem5);

    DrawerAdapter adapter = new DrawerAdapter(getActivity(), drawerItems);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

This is the activity onCreate() where the setContentView is throwing the exception -

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); //This is where the exception occurs

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}
```

This is where my DrawerLayout is -

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
```

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.labs.thinkdifferent.voice.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: So the exception points to `setContentView()`?

Comment: yes, its in the setContentView() of HomeActivity...

Comment: I don't see anything illegal in `onCreateView()`, do you override any other callbacks in the fragment? Actually, could you post more lines of the stacktrace please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll take a shot and suggest you get the error because you return `mDrawerListView` in `onCreateView()` instead of `group`. The returned from `onCreateView()` view is itself attached to another view hierarchy, which is impossible in this case because from the XML layout it already has a parent `ViewGroup`.

I can see nothing preventing from returning `group` in `onCreateView()`.